# osx macport Xlib: extension "RECORD" missing on display ":0"

Tags: macos, macports, xlib

I'm trying to run gnee on OSX using Macport installation (2.1.2) and I've just installed it using

sudo port install gnee.

It is installed and it launches fine however when I go to record, I get the message in the title.

From looking online, I see that it most likely means I'm missing the librecord.so module from my X11 installation.

I have no idea how to resolve this though.  Anyone able to help me do this for the macport installation?

Answer (score 1):

Error message tells that your X server does not have RECORD extension enabled. You can see list of extensions your server supports with `xdpyinfo | grep -r extensions -A 30`)

If you are using XQuartz server then this command might help: `defaults write org.x.X11 enable_test_extensions -boolean true` (see CUSTOMISATION section in XQuartz [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/Xquartz.1.html))

Comment: I tried adding `defaults write org.x.X11 enable_test_extensions -boolean true`, but RECORD extension didn't appear.